# Add Attachment File Button in Library Form Sharepoint 2013

Tags: attachments, forms-library

I want to add Attachment File Button (like attachment in email / Browse button  before upload something file) in Library Form Sharepoint 2013. So, when I fill that form, I could attach some files.

Comment: by Library form you mean NewForm.aspx of a document library?

Comment: the newform for any document library already has an attach file button, what exactly are you looking for? are you using a custom form for uploading documents to library?

Comment: Hi Mr Zakir HC,

Yes, I want using custom form in Library SharePoint 2013.
In Library standart SP 2013, we can upload a file/document.

But in my case, I want to have a column/field in Library Form which  that column could attach another file/document.

So,
List :: Create Item -> Fill some fields and can attach file/document.
Library :: Create Document / Upload Document -> Fill some fields and *could attach another file/document too.

Thank you.
Best Regards,

Galih

Answer (score 2):

This link might be able to help you.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function AttachFile()
{
    SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance().executeRootCommand("Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.AttachFile", null, null, null);
}
</script>
<a onclick='javascript:AttachFile();'>browse</a>
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/31a8cf62-db68-4fb8-8c15-3748c67eb989/add-attachment-button-to-a-custom-new-form-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: it works, but I had to rename AttachFile() function because there is another system function with this name. Perfect! anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use Info Path to attached a file in the form and you can easily put attachment field where you want in the form. 
For more info see this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-a-file-attachment-control-8e8e102f-fad5-4440-bc28-d28944f85287